# Show the percentage of php with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json

Sorry about this.
I tried to make this process does not work me.
I have this code:

```
function paypalFees($sub_total, $round_fee) {

// Set Fee Rate Variables
$fee_percent = '8'; // Paypal's percentage rate per transaction (3.4% in UK)
$fee_cash = '0.00'; // Paypal's set cash amount per transaction (Â£0.20 in UK)

// Calculate Fees
$paypal_fee = ((($sub_total / 100) * $fee_percent) + $fee_cash);

if ($round_fee == true) {
    $paypal_fee = ceil($paypal_fee);
}

// Calculate Grand Total
$grand_total = ($sub_total + $paypal_fee);

// Tidy Up Numbers
$sub_total = number_format($sub_total, 2, '.', ',');
$paypal_fee = number_format($paypal_fee, 2, '.', ',');
$grand_total = number_format($grand_total, 2, '.', ',');

// Return Array
return array('grand_total'=>$grand_total, 'paypal_fee'=>$paypal_fee, 'sub_total'=>$sub_total);
```

to see the result I have to put establish a number:

```
$receipt = paypalFees('150.00', false);
```

the result is shown by

```
<h2>Your Receipt</h2>
<li>Sub-Total: &pound;<?php print $receipt['sub_total']; ?></li>
<li>Booking Fee: &pound;<?php print $receipt['paypal_fee']; ?></li>
<li>TOTAL: &pound;<?php print $receipt['grand_total']; ?></li>
```

to see the result I have to refresh the page.

How could do this process without refreshing the page, with ajax? 
an example: 
[Sum HTML Textbox Values using jQuery / JavaScript](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/sum-html-textbox-values-using-jquery-javascript/)

Comment: Look into web sockets, e.g. http://pusher.com

Comment: You could either use AJAX, or you could do all the calculations in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the workflow of your application whatsoever here is my best guess:

1. Take your code out of the function.
2. Make your main display page a PHP page with your normal HTML elements
3. use the code your provided and echo out the values

If you are simply displaying results onload then you can do this my way. If you need interaction with the user and the database you need AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the data without refreshing the page, you would have to write the `paypalFees()` function in JavaScript. Instead of returning an array, you just use JavaScript to set the content of spans, like so:

```
<h2>Your Receipt</h2>
<li>Sub-Total: &pound;<span id="receipt_subtotal"></span></li>
<li>Booking Fee: &pound;<span id="paypal_fee"></span></li>
<li>TOTAL: &pound;<span id="receipt_total"></span></li>
```

Then have JavaScript set the content of the spans.

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like this:

```
<?php // getpourcent.php
function paypalFees($sub_total, $round_fee) {

  // Set Fee Rate Variables
  $fee_percent = '8'; // Paypal's percentage rate per transaction (3.4% in UK)
  $fee_cash = '0.00'; // Paypal's set cash amount per transaction (Â£0.20 in UK)

  // Calculate Fees
  $paypal_fee = ((($sub_total / 100) * $fee_percent) + $fee_cash);

  if ($round_fee == true) {
      $paypal_fee = ceil($paypal_fee);
  }

  // Calculate Grand Total
  $grand_total = ($sub_total + $paypal_fee);

  // Tidy Up Numbers
  $sub_total = number_format($sub_total, 2, '.', ',');
  $paypal_fee = number_format($paypal_fee, 2, '.', ',');
  $grand_total = number_format($grand_total, 2, '.', ',');

  // Return Array
  return array('grand_total'=>$grand_total, 'paypal_fee'=>$paypal_fee, 'sub_total'=>$sub_total);
}

exit(json_encode(paypalFees($_POST['sub_total'], $_POST['round_fee'])));
?>
```

you function but with a `json_encode` output.

And an other one file (client) with a jquery getson call in a setInterval:

```
<h2>Your Receipt From @Ramsay Smith (thx)</h2>
<li>Sub-Total: &pound;<span id="receipt_subtotal"></span></li>
<li>Booking Fee: &pound;<span id="paypal_fee"></span></li>
<li>TOTAL: &pound;<span id="receipt_total"></span></li>
<script>
function getPourcent()
{
  $.getJSON('getpourcent.php', { 'sub_total': 0, 'round_fee': 0 }, function (data)
  {
    // take a look to the @Ramsay Smith code
    $('#receipt_subtotal').text(data.sub_total);
    $('#paypal_fee').text(data.paypal_fee);
    $('#receipt_total').text(data.grand_total);
  });
}

setInterval(getPourcent, 500);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Use below Javascript object to achieve this,modify it according to your need*

```js
var generateReceipt = {

  paypalFees: function(round_fee) {
    var sub_total = $('#tb').val();
    
    var fee_percent = '8'; // Paypal's percentage rate per transaction (3.4% in UK)
    var fee_cash = '0.00'; // Paypal's set cash amount per transaction (Â£0.20 in UK)
    // Calculate Fees
    var paypal_fee = (((sub_total / 100) * fee_percent) + fee_cash );

   if (round_fee == true) {
      paypal_fee = ceil(paypal_fee);
    }
    

    // Calculate Grand Total
    var grand_total = (sub_total + paypal_fee);

    // Tidy Up Numbers
    sub_total = generateReceipt.number_format(sub_total, 2, '.', ',');
    
    paypal_fee = generateReceipt.number_format(paypal_fee, 2, '.', ',');
    
    grand_total = generateReceipt.number_format(grand_total, 2, '.', ',');

    // Return Array
    return alert('Grand_Total:' + grand_total + 'Paypal_Fee:' + paypal_fee + 'Sub_Total:' + sub_total);

  },

  number_format: function(number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {
    // Strip all characters but numerical ones.
    number = (number + '').replace(/[^0-9+\-Ee.]/g, '');
    var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number,
      prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals),
      sep = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousands_sep,
      dec = (typeof dec_point === 'undefined') ? '.' : dec_point,
      s = '',
      toFixedFix = function(n, prec) {
        var k = Math.pow(10, prec);
        return '' + Math.round(n * k) / k;
      };
    // Fix for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
    s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : '' + Math.round(n)).split('.');
    if (s[0].length > 3) {
      s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep);
    }
    if ((s[1] || '').length < prec) {
      s[1] = s[1] || '';
      s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1).join('0');
    }
    return s.join(dec);
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type ='text'
  name = 'fee'
  id = 'tb' >

<input type='button'
  name ='calculate' value='Calculate'
  onclick = 'generateReceipt.paypalFees();' >
```